# Creating multiple versions of the same app

Tags: github

Let's say the app is written for 3 environments. For example a theme made for WP, Drupal and Joomla. So there are 3 versions of the theme.

Do I have to create a repo for each of them? Because I don't like that idea.

Does Github provide a way to put them all in one repo?

Comment: Perhaps put each version into a different folder for each environment and push it that way?

Comment: yes, but if I download the ZIP thing, it's all the stuff inside, not just the version I want to download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all your files in one repo. If you have three separate folders for each version in your main repo, then you can have three versions while having one repo.

Answer (score 1):

There are no rules about the structure of a repository. Your repo could consist of three folders, one for each version of the app.

Or you could keep them as different branches.